# Got unexpected compile warning about packed structure

Tags: c++

When I ran the following code snippet, got warning, not sure why. The g++ has version 4.8.4.

```
$ g++ -g  -fPIC -std=c++11 -fpermissive te.cc
te.cc:25:11: warning: ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field ‘cMacAddr strArp::src_hw_mac’ [enabled by default]
  cMacAddr src_hw_mac;
           ^
te.cc:27:11: warning: ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field ‘cMacAddr strArp::dst_hw_mac’ [enabled by default]
  cMacAddr dst_hw_mac;
```

Code snippet "te.cc"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int uint;

char _ethHdrPrintBuf[100];

class cMacAddr {
public:
    uchar addr[6];
    cMacAddr() { for (int i=0; i<6; i++) addr[i] = 0;}
};

struct strArp {
    uint16 hw_type;
    uint16 proto_type;
    uchar  hw_size;
    uchar  proto_size;
    uint16 opcode;
    cMacAddr src_hw_mac;
    uint  src_proto_ipv4;
    cMacAddr dst_hw_mac;
    uint  dst_proto_ipv4;
} __attribute__((__packed__ )) ;
int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(strArp) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory.  `cMacAddr` is a "non-POD" field, and is not packed, so the `strArp` is forced to ignore the `__packed__` attribute.

Comment: @chad:  if I drop `__attribute__((__packed__ ))`, I don't see the warning, however, the structure strArp is 4 bytes bigger.

Answer (score 0):

`cMacAddr` has a constructor, therefore it can't be a POD. Too much detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821).

Comment: thanks for the link. But having  `__attribute__((__packed__ ))` give me the desired result in terms of size of the struct. How do I remove the warning then?

Comment: Either remove the constructor from `cMacAddr`, or give that the `__packed__` attribute as well.

Comment: If it were me, I'd declare with a POD class for `cMacAddr`. You can zero out the structure in some way other than the constructor.